# SSRS actual parameter values are overriden by default values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have set default values for my ssrs report. 
[Setting in my Report Parameter Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNJl3.jpg)

This works when I preview the report.

The problem is that when I have deployed the rdl and when I generate a report I am getting the default values and not the actual values on the generated pdf.

Things I have tried:
Redeploying the report.
Restarting the SSRS services.

Kindly help me out

Comment: Are you saying you manually input a value into the parameters, and you click View Report, it doesn't use the parameter? Or doesn't print it on the report? What field expression in your report shows the parameter?

Comment: I don;t hink this is your problem but just in case FYI: If you have previously deployed the report with different defaults, they will not be overwritten unless you delete the report from the server and redeploy.

Comment: This is the value I pass through XML and yes I have tried deleting the RDL and pushing it again, It still shows me the default values instead of the actual values from the service\logic.